# MySQL: Output datetime field in query by combining two fields

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have two fields.

1. `teststartdatetime` - datatype: datetime, start of test.
2. `testendtime` - datatype: mediumtext, text of endtime in "00:00:00" format

I need to query my db to output a new field `testenddatetime` (as datetime datetype) which contains both the time part of the `testendtime` field and the date from the `teststartdatetime` field.

Also, I need it to check that the value of the `testendtime` field is later than the value of the time portion of the `teststartdatetime` field. And if not then increase the `testenddatetime` by one day.

> *Note: Tests are no longer than 24hrs*

Feel free to play around with it at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6bc80/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `concat()` do what you want?

```
select concat(date(teststartdatetime), ' ', testendtime)
```

Storing times as a string is a really bad idea because MySQL has a `time` datatype.

As for the check:

```
select (case when time(teststartdatetime) > time(testendtime)
             then concat(date(teststartdatetime) + interval 1 day, ' ', testendtime)
             else concat(date(teststartdatetime), ' ', testendtime)
        end)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can only query the db as I do not own it but will make the suggestion. Also thank for the answer, could you also integrate the additional check in my question? Otherwise `testenddatetime` will be less that `teststartdatetime` on occasion. Thankyou